# Powershell - capture EXE output

Tags: powershell, logging, exe, file-io

I wrote a script to run a Reflect disk image backup in powershell. to call the command to run Reflect I use:

```
& "C:\folders\reflect.exe" -e -w -diff "C:\folders\backup.xml" | Out-Null
```

This calls the reflect.exe and fires the backup up without output to the console just fine. However, reflect outputs text to the console when the backup runs if there is not Out-Null. Information about what its doing ect. When I change the command to:

```
& "C:\folders\reflect.exe" -e -w -diff "C:\folders\backup.xml" | Out-File "C:\logfile.log" -append
```

to capture this output there is nothing in the log file. I am guessing it is because reflect is outputting to the cmd prompt. How can I get that data? I have also tried the magical '2>&1' string and reflect picks it up as a argument.

Thanks!

edit:

Here's my exact code:

```
$loc_reflect = "C:\Program Files\Macrium\Reflect\reflect.exe" # Reflect location
$bak_type = $t # backup type from params 'full' or 'diff'
$dir_scripts = "C:\util\Backups\" # Scripts Dir
$fld_bin = "Bin\" # Path to Bin in scripts dir
$bak_src_norm = "M6600_all.xml" # Backup xml for normal in bin
$bak_args = @('-e', '-w') # array of arguments used in the backup command
[Array]$rargs = $bak_args + @("-$bak_type", "$dir_scripts$fld_bin$bak_src_norm")
& $loc_reflect $rargs | Out-Null
```

or

```
& $loc_reflect $rargs 2>&1 | Out-File "C:\logfile.log" -append
```

Thanks guys!

Comment: Nothing seems to be wrong with what you are doing there. So, file is getting created but nothing in it?

Comment: Include an example of using 2>&1 - it sounds like you need that but may have used it incorrectly.

Comment: File is created but is blank, Edited the original!

Comment: @JasonShirk `Out-Null` doesn't capture output on the error stream, so redirecting that stream shouldn't have any effect.

Comment: @nat45928 What do you get when you capture the command output in a variable and write that to a file? `$var = & $loc_reflect ...; $var > 'C:\logfile.log'`

Comment: Same thing, I tried `$var = $(& $loc_reflect $rargs | write-output); $var > 'C:\test.log'` just a blank file. `$var = & $loc_reflect $rargs; $var > 'C:\test.log'` was another blank file. For all of these I saw output in the console.

Comment: The program uses StdOut in the VBscript it generates if that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following...

`& $loc_reflect $rargs >> "C:\logfile.log" 2>&1`

This is based some quick research on PowerShell output redirection. There may be something awkward with Reflect though as noted on the Macrium support forum...

http://support.macrium.com/topic.asp?TOPIC_ID=624